# Format Squish tool report to robot framework report

Tags: json, xml, squish, jira-xray

We are using XRay's cloud APIs to upload execution reports to change the execution status of test cases. But the execution report is generated from Squish tool but not from robot framework or cucumber etc. As per the documentation from XRay https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/XRAYCLOUD/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST , Squish reports are not supported. How do I customize this squish XML report that will be understood by XRay APIs and update test results? Any experts?

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly with Squish docs, [it can generate JUnit XML reports](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rg-cmdline.html#rg-squishrunner-cli) which you can then submit back to Xray, either using the Xray REST API directly or by using one the CI plugins (e.g. Jenkins plugin).
Xray will then auto-provision Test issues based on the JUnit XML report following the rules [here-in defined](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Taking+advantage+of+JUnit+XML+reports).
In sum, generate JUnit XML reports and submit them to the Xray REST API.

Note: depending on the information that you need to have visibility of in Xray/Jira, the JUnit XML report may or not be enough. If you need more detailed information you may have to use a different format and have a way of building out a report in that format. More on the capabilities of each format [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Integrating+with+Testing+Frameworks).

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach by the vendor of Squish is to import the Squish test results into their [Squish Test Center](https://www.froglogic.com/testcenter/) product, and that will then push the results into Xray. (Also see "[Integration for Xray](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish-testcenter/latest/ao-testcenter-xray.html)".)